# Apart from Serbia, have there been pro-Russia/pro-Putin demonstrations in other countries, since the war started?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine, protests, serbia

https://www.bbc.com/news/av/world-europe-60630351

> Up to 4,000 people have taken part in a pro-Russia demonstration in the Serbian capital.
>
> Friday's march was a show of support for Moscow after its invasion of Ukraine.

In the accompanying video, you can see them holding portraits of Putin and even the "Z" sign that was present on some Russian vehicles in the (Southern) invasion force.

Have any similar public rallies, in support of the Russian actions, taken place in other countries?

Comment: We are not hearing a lot from the Ukraine rebel areas nor the the rebels since the invasion, but perhaps that is our cherry picking.

Comment: Is the question only about european countries?

Comment: @convert: no, obviously, I (first) accepted an answer that starts with an example from Africa. (On 2nd thought, a more complete answer has been posted since, so I change my accept to that one.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to the above answers:

TL;DR:

Demonstrations, regardless of size, have been seen in:

- Damascus, Syria
- Nicosia, Cyprus
- Sydney, Australia
- Kazan, Republic of Tatarstan *(a semi-autonomous region) - so, still Russia I guess...*
- Ethiopia
- Bamako, Mali
- New Delhi, India
- Bethlehem, West Bank
- Tel-Aviv, Israel
- Netanya, Israel
- Niksic, Montenegro
- Larnaca, Cyprus
- Sana'a, Yemen
- Bishkek, Kyrgyzstan

*(Note: a few are from social media rather than a news article, as searching for more information pro-russian returns fewer results..)*

https://youtu.be/Ifnf12uO76U

> PRO-RUSSIAN demonstration has taken place at Damascus university in Syria, as students parade around in Russian military 'Z' formation.

> Syrian university students and professors held a pro-Russia demonstration in Damascus on March 9, Russian and Syrian state media reported.

Related:

https://www.independent.co.uk/tv/news/prorussia-z-damascus-university-demonst

> Pro-Russia students form giant ‘Z’ during Damascus University demonstration

> Syrian students and professors formed a giant 'Z' during a pro-Russia demonstration at Damascus University.

> Dozens of people were filmed waving Russian flags at the university march before crowds formed the shape of a Z.

[image]

https://cyprus-mail.com/2022/03/12/pro-putin-protest-outside-nicosia-embassy/

> Pro-Putin protest outside Nicosia embassy
> March 12, 2022

> A small group of people gathered outside the Russian embassy on Saturday in support of the country’s invasion of Ukraine and President Vladimir Putin.

> A few dozen people waving Russian flags stood outside the Russian embassy in Nicosia, using the motto “Putin Great Leader”.

[image]

https://www.dailyadvent.com/gb/news/ccd0665a5affd4ebebfbf68b1efafcdb-ProRussian-protesters-bring-their-war-to

https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-10596797/Pro-Russia-protesters-Putin

> Pro-Russian protesters bring their war to Sydney as they march outside Russia's consulate in SUPPORT of the horrific invasion of Ukraine
>
> - Loyalists took to the streets outside Russia's Sydney embassy to back invasion
> - Sydney-based supporters repeatedly shown support there over past two weeks
> - Dozens stood outside Woollahra consulate on Wednesday holding Russian flags

[image]

https://www.ladbible.com/news/russian-students-wearing-z-symbol-hold-pro-war-

> Russian Students Dressed In White Gowns Emblazoned With 'Z' Symbol Host Eerie Pro-War Rally

> Russian students wearing white jackets emblazoned with a black 'Z' symbol have staged a pro-war rally at a Kazan university.

> In footage released on social media, the students in the patriotic flash mob can be seen chanting while saluting and raising their fists to the sky.

> The group descended on a Kazan shopping centre before chanting 'Russia for peace' and 'forward Russia'.

> *However it has since been revealed that students were threatened with expulsion if they did not attend.
> German journalist Julian Roepcke initially reported that students could only get out of the mandatory demonstration with 'an explanatory note'.*

[image]

https://www.nytimes.com/2022/03/03/world/africa/russia-ukraine-eritrea-africa.html

> In Ethiopia, Russian flags flew at a ceremony on Wednesday to commemorate a famous 19th century battle against Italian invaders, recalling the involvement of Russian volunteers who sided with Ethiopian fighters.

[image]

Bamako, Mali:

https://www.ghsplash.com/pro-russia-protest-in-mali-in-support-amidst-russia-ukraine-conflict/

> Pro-Russia protest happened in Mali amidst the Russia Ukraine conflict.

[image]

*(Note: t-shirts with “Je Suis Wagner” on them)*

https://www.dw.com/en/who-are-the-indians-supporting-russias-invasion-of-ukraine/a

> In New Delhi earlier this month, members of Hindu Sena, an Indian right-wing organisation, organized a demonstration in support of Russia and its invasion of Ukraine.

> Marching in the heart of the capital for almost an hour, the demonstrators held signs reading "Russia, you fight, we are with you" and "Long live India-Russia ties." Other signs explicitly supported the invasion and an "undivided Russia."

[image]

https://www.timesofisrael.com/liveblog_entry/palestinians-in-bethlehem-hold-small-rally-in-support-of-russia/

> Palestinians in Bethlehem hold small rally in support of Russia

> ..small pro-Russia rally in Bethlehem in the West Bank.
> Both the Palestinian Authority and Hamas, the two main Palestinian factions, have avoided taking a stance on Russia’s invasion of Ukraine.

> But historic ties bind other Palestinians with Moscow. Many studied in the former Soviet Union, which also provided aid and comfort for years to the Palestine Liberation Organization.

[image]

*(Rough translation: Bethlehem donated by President Abu Ali Putin)*

https://scooptrade.com/residents-of-tel-aviv-organized-a-rally-in-support-of-russia/

Tel-Aviv and Netanya, Israel

[image]

https://youtu.be/ 4A-3K-SmYc4

https://oopstop.com/rally-in-support-of-russia-takes-place-in-israel/

> “Today, two rallies were announced in Netanya: “For the Russian world” and “against the Russian world”. According to the organizers, they will be held from 12.00 to 17.00,” the news agency reports. The Israeli Labor Weekdays Telegram channel clarifies that the Israeli police forces are aimed at ensuring that the participants in the rally “For the Russian World” and “against the Russian World” do not meet.

> Also on the website of the news agency it is reported that a motor rally in support of Russia took place in Tel Aviv. A video with the convoy has already been published. She is reportedly moving towards holding a pro-Russian rally.

[image]

*Just checking it was held in Tel-Aviv..* on HaYarkon Street.

https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/serb-nationalists-montenegro-rally-support-russia-2022-02-28/

Niksic, Montenegro

> Orthodox nationalists pose with the banner that reads "Serbs in Montenegro - Russians in Ukraine" in solidarity with their "Russian brothers", who they support in their ongoing invasion of Ukraine, in Niksic, Montenegro.

[image]

https://www.urdupoint.com/en/world/around-300-people-gather-for-pro-russian-rall-1488272.html

> A rally in support of Russia, organized by the Coordination Council of Russian Compatriots in Cyprus and local activists, took place in the Cypriot city of Larnaca on Saturday.

[image]

https://www.gettyimages.no/detail/news-photo/yemenis-participate-in-a-protest-staged-for-supp

> Yemenis participate in a protest staged for supporting Russian President Vladimir Vladimirovich Putin in his war on Ukraine, outside the Russian embassy

[image]

https://eurasianet.org/ukraine-war-inspires-rival-passions-in-central-asia

https://24.kg/obschestvo/226465_situatsiya_vukraine_vbishkeke_prohodit_miting_vpodderjku_rossii/

> “For eight years, the inhabitants of Donbass have been waiting for the end of Nazi actions by the Ukrainian authorities, all this time they have endured, but there is no point in being silent. We must rise up and come out against Nazism. Our grandfathers went through this already. Today we came out to express our gratitude to the guys who defend peace on the whole planet, Kyrgyzstan is with you,”

[image]

Comment: Your answer could use a  bit of a summary at the top where these took place.

Comment: "Kazan, Republic of Tatarstan (a semi-autonomous region) - so, still Russia I guess..." Yes still Russia.

Comment: Yes, I added that as it seemed pointless to add a rally in support of Pro-war Russia that was in.. Russia.. but kept it in as the article was interesting - I had read elsewhere about enforced pro-war rallying...

Answer (score 18):

Yes - in Bangui, the capital of the Central African Republic, there have been a few demonstrations in support of Russia. On February 23rd, there was [a demonstration](https://www.voanews.com/a/car-capital-pays-tribute-to-national-army-russian-soldiers/6457665.html) in support of Russian paramilitary forces which defended the city against rebel forces in 2021.

[France24](https://www.france24.com/en/live-news/20220224-bangui-hails-russian-saviours-of-battered-c-africa), reporting on the same event, mentioned that there was also some support for the country’s actions in Ukraine:

> About a hundred people of all ages waved Russian and CAR flags before troops from an elite unit and figures close to the government.
>
> Some held up banners and signs proclaiming "Central Africans with Russia" and even "Russia will save the Donbass from war" -- a reference to the Ukrainian territory that President Vladimir Putin cited as justification for Thursday's attack.

Post-invasion, on March 5th, there was a further protest in support of Russia’s actions in the capital, according to [Africa News](https://www.africanews.com/2022/03/05/pro-russia-protesters-rally-in-central-african-republic/):

> A hundred people participated Saturday in Bangui, the capital of Central African Republic, in a demonstration in support of Russia in its offensive against Ukraine, noted a journalist from AFP.
>
> The demonstrators gathered at the foot of a statue, inaugurated in late 2021 by President Faustin Archange Touadéra, representing Russian fighters protecting a woman and her children. Many waved Russian and Central African flags in the heart of the capital, near the university.

> The demonstrators held up signs proclaiming "Russia saves Donbass", in reference to this pro-Russian separatist territory in eastern Ukraine, or "Russia and Central Africa against Nazism" and "It's Nato's fault".

Below is a photo of the event that the journalist Clement Di Roma [posted on Twitter](https://twitter.com/clementdiroma/status/1500101695736619011), the sign reads “Russia & CAR against Nazism”.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

There was also a rally at Aleppo University in Syria in support of Russia according to the [Syrian Arab News Agency](https://www.sana.sy/en/?p=266077):

> Students and professors of Aleppo University participated on Thursday in a solidarity stand with a Russia.
>
> SANA reporter in Aleppo province said that students, professors, and employees at Aleppo University staged a stand in solidarity with the Russian Federation in the university square.
>
> The participants expressed their solidarity with the Russian people and leadership, and rejection of the US and Western policies aiming at undermining its security and stability.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since many places were already mentioned in previous answers, I´ll list only the ones not mentioned befor.

[Yerevan Armenia](https://brandnewtube.com/watch/rally-in-support-of-russia-is-now-taking-place-in-yerevan-armenia-near-the-russian-embassy_QJc2M7W9ywSRVf1.html) There is also an [article about this raly](https://eadaily.com/ru/news/2022/03/19/armeniya-podderzhala-rossiyu-massovym-mitingom-v-erevane-byli-est-i-budem-vmeste?ysclid=l17seh94qy):

> In Yerevan today, March 19, a mass rally is held in support of Russia,
> which continues a special military operation in Ukraine to
> demilitarize and denazify this country.
>
> There are a lot of Russian and Armenian flags, posters with slogans
> about the friendship of the two allied states at the action in the
> center of the capital of the Transcaucasian republic at this moment. A
> drum show is underway, an EADaily correspondent reports from the scene

In western media this rally is called a rally of minority, but even then it should be still a suitable answer to the question.

[Bulgaria](https://en.news-front.info/2022/03/03/bulgarians-initiate-action-in-support-of-russia/)

[Beirut Lebanon](https://baltija.eu/2022/03/03/v-stolicze-livana-proshyol-miting-v-podderzhku-rossii-i-zhitelej-donbassa/):

> The actions of Russia in Ukraine were supported by the inhabitants of
> Lebanon, Russian compatriots and local residents went to the Russian
> embassy in Beirut to a rally in support of the Russian fight against
> the Nazis and the population of the DPR and LPR, RIA Novosti reports.
>
> The action was initiated by activists of the Russian community in
> Lebanon. According to the rally participants, they oppose the Nazis
> and NATO aggression and came out to express solidarity with the
> Russians and residents of the Donbass republics. The rally is being
> held under police protection, the Ukrainian diaspora has threatened to
> disrupt the event.
>
> Teresa, a local resident, said that participation in the rally is only
> a small part of which the Lebanese can repay Russia for help and
> support over the years. Teresa said that in her country they are well
> aware of what a war with the Nazis is, and expressed her conviction
> that Russia can win.
>
> Russkiy Mir reported that rallies in support of Russia were held in
> Brazil, Montenegro and other countries. A mass march will take place
> in Belgrade on March 4 in support of Russia's stated goals of
> denazification and demilitarization in Ukraine.

[Brazil](https://baltija.eu/2022/03/02/v-brazilii-proveli-akczii-v-podderzhku-rossii/):

> Members of the Brazilian radical left party "Workers' Interest"
> appealed to the country's authorities to recognize the republics of
> Donbass, TASS reports. With such slogans, they came to the actions
> under the general title “We all support Russia”, which took place the
> day before, on March 1, in front of the Russian embassy and consulates
> general in Brasilia, Rio de Janeiro and Sao Paulo.
>
> The rally participants sharply criticized NATO's course aimed at the
> militarization of Ukraine. They were holding banners “For the defeat
> of NATO in Ukraine”, “We all support Russia”.
>
> Representatives of the conservative-liberal Movement Free Brazil party
> tried to prevent the demonstration in Rio de Janeiro. They covered
> themselves with banners with their own symbols and, broadcasting live
> on the Internet, loudly insulted political opponents and shouted
> slogans of Ukrainian nationalists. As a result, the police had to be
> called.
>
> Actions in Brasilia and Sao Paulo passed peacefully.
>
> As Russkiy Mir reported, Brazilian President Jair Bolsonaro refused to
> support the UN resolution if it criticizes Russia's actions in Ukraine
> or proposes sanctions against Russia. Bolsonaro reminded that Russia
> and Ukraine are inhabited by fraternal peoples, and the majority of
> the population of Ukraine speaks Russian. The President assured that
> he would take into account practical considerations in his actions.

[Cuba](https://news-front.info/2022/05/02/na-kube-podderzhali-rossiju-i-ee-armiju/?ysclid=l2opw56971):

> Russian troops and Russian President Vladimir Putin are being
> supported even in Cuba. A May Day demonstration took place in Havana,
> where they demonstrated the symbol of the special operation in Ukraine
> Z.
>
> This is reported by the political magazine PolitExpert, referring to
> the Russian embassy in Cuba. Diplomats posted a photo on social
> networks showing how they carry the Russian flag with the Latin letter
> Z.
>
> At the same time, the rally by May 1 was held in the country for the
> first time in three years. It has been canceled twice before due to
> the COVID-19 pandemic. Actions were held throughout the country and
> hundreds of thousands of people took part in them.
>
> Two participants in the rally in the Cuban capital carried the Russian
> flag right next to the guest podium, where guests from the Russian
> Federation were also present. Put the letter Z on the tricolor,
> expressing support for the army that is fighting Nazism in Ukraine

[Australia](https://news-front.info/2023/02/18/zhiteli-avstralii-vyshli-na-miting-v-podderzhku-rossii/):

> **Residents of Australia came to a rally in support of Russia**
>
> In Sydney, Australia, about 1.5 thousand people took part in a rally
> in support of Russia. The action was held next to the Russian
> Consulate General.
>
> The participants of the rally posted a video online. In the video
> footage, the Australians drove cars with the letters Z. to the
> building of the Russian Consulate General. A portrait of Russian
> President Vladimir Putin was installed on the podium.
>
> According to the participants of the action, a friendly atmosphere
> prevailed at the event. People were treated to drinks and food from
> the field kitchen.
>
> According to Boikov, the rally was mainly attended by Australians. The
> participants of the action brought posters with inscriptions: "Ukraine
> is a terrorist state. Support Russia!" and "No war with Russia!".
>
> The action was also attended by Serbian bikers who raised Russian
> flags at the stadium in Melbourne during the Australian Open.

[Italy](https://news-front.info/2023/03/20/za-putina-v-italii-prodolzhajutsja-manifestacii-v-podderzhku-rossii/):

> **"For Putin": demonstrations in support of Russia continue in Italy**
>
> Demonstrations continue in Italy in support of Russia, for Italy's
> withdrawal from the war, against the NATO regime. This is reported by
> one of the TG channels.
>
> Demonstrations in support of Russia continue in Italy. Hundreds of
> people took to the Grand Canal Street with flags of the Russian
> Federation to speak out against sending weapons to Ukraine, against
> Russophobia, against the Anglo-Saxon world, in support of Russia and
> Putin. Another demand of activists is Italy's withdrawal from NATO.
>
> The rally caused a resonance. The local press is full of newspaper
> headlines: "Russian flags against NATO!". And then a loud continuation
> of the headline: "on Canal Grande Street, a demonstration of the right
> took place with many groups in support of Putin and notes of nostalgia
> for the Soviet Union."
>
> "The Russian flag is triumphant" — this is how the article of one of
> the local publications begins.
>
> The entire demonstration was accompanied by words with slogans of
> struggle and unity "from the time of the Stalinist Soviet Union and
> the Comintern."
>
> "The West is planning the destruction of Russia with the help of the
> conflict in Ukraine. America has destroyed many countries that
> resisted globalization and the dominance of the United States, and
> only Russia firmly defends its position. While the West is plunging
> into Satanism, Russia and the countries supporting it want to live in
> traditional spiritual values. Europe and, above all, Italy must resist
> Euro—Atlanticism, which has crossed all borders and must be eliminated
> once and for all!", said Frederica Francesconi, an activist of the
> United for Freedom movement, in her speech.
>
> In turn, the president of the Association "Russia Emilia Romagna" Luca
> Rossi said that the Ukrainian people are a victim of the Kiev criminal
> regime, and the Ukrainian minority, located in Italy, and supporting
> this criminal regime, is simply blinded by ethnic and religious
> hatred.
>
> The authorities tried to prevent the rally, but the activists were
> determined and continued their march shouting: "For Putin, for Russia!
> Italy is against the war!".

Comment: Just for context: Armenia is supplied with subsidized weapons from Russia and recently lost a lot of territory to Aserbaijan, which was able to soundly defeat Armenia in no small part because of weapons that the west supplied. Now Europe is buying gas and oil from Aserbaijan's dictatorship... If this isn't enough: There is an embargo on delivering weapons to *either* country that has been in force for more than 30 years, is supported on paper by both Russia and "the west" and has been ignored by many countries with some notable exceptions (e.g. Germany).

Answer (score 1):

Palestinians have been documented to support Putin's special military operation in Ukraine.

**REFERENCES:**

> A song performed at a Palestinian wedding called on Russian President Vladimir Putin to increase attacks against Ukraine and on China to invade Taiwan. One of the singers asked Putin to banish the Ukrainians to Palestine so Palestinians can marry Ukrainian women. He added that China should invade Taiwan so "we will smash the nose of the Americans," who manufacture Israeli airplanes. A video of the performance by singers Mohammed Arani and Suhaib Al-Jamma'ini was posted on various online Palestinian sources on March 4, 2022.

*MEMRI, Mar 04, 2022. Song Performed At Palestinian Wedding: 'Harden Your Heart, Oh Putin; Increase Your Attacks... Banish [Ukrainians] To Palestine And We Will Marry Ukrainian Women... We Say To China: Invade Taiwan [To] Smash The Nose Of The Americans': https://www.memri.org/tv/palestinian-wedding-song-putin-banish-ukrainian-women-to-marry-palestinians-china-invade-taiwan*